# Please correct my calculation for the differentiation of an extremely basic yet simple single-symbol abstract function

Tags: calculus

(Foreword: Sorry to bother this platform with this extremely simple confusion, but I've been stuck on this trivial question for a good 3.5 hours, leading to anguish/frustrated to the point that again (and in the past countless times) want to change another self-study textbook, or even give up (although it will not come true because of unwillingness).)

---

In the book "*Introduction to Analysis*" (by 高木貞治) → Chapter 3 "Integral Method" → Section 38 "Approximate Calculation of Definite Integrals" → "[Integration of cubic polynomials]":
( Scanned images [１](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idvIV.png) and [２](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUNZB.png) of the two pages about this)

> $$
> \varphi(h)=
>   \int_{-h}^h f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
>   - \dfrac{h}{3}(f(h)+f(-h)+4f(0)),
> $$
> by a simple calculation get
> $$
> \begin{gather*}
> \varphi(0)=\varphi'(0)=\varphi''(0)=0,\\
> \varphi'''(h)=-\dfrac{h}{3}(f'''(h)-f'''(-h))
> \end{gather*}
> $$

---

I am <del>fairly</del> confident that the following set of expressions should be correct (actually incorrect; eventually ${\color{red}{\texttt{correct}}}{\color{maroon}{\texttt{ed}}}$) by referring to the *First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* etc. (and even verified them by giving two small examples):
$$
\newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
\begin{rcases}
\left( \int_  0 ^h  f(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x \right)' =  f( h) \\
\left( \int_{-h}^0  f(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x \right)' = -f(-h){\color{red}{(-h)'}}{\color{maroon}{=f(-h)}} \\
(f(-h))' = -f'(-h)
\end{rcases}
$$

Based on them, the following calculations are derived ($\color{orange}{\texttt{Corrected and solved}}$ based on answer):
$$
\require{cancel}
\newcommand{\C}[1]{{\color{orange}{#1}}}
\begin{align*}
  \varphi'  (h) &= f(h) \boldsymbol{\C+} f(-h) - \dfrac{1}{3}(f(h)+f(-h){\color{gray}{+4f(0)}}) - \dfrac{h}{3}(f'(h)-f'(-h)) \\
                &= \dfrac{2}{3}f(h) \C+ \dfrac{\C2}{3}f(-h){\color{gray}{ - \dfrac{4}{3}f(0)}} - \dfrac{h}{3}(f'(h)-f'(-h)), \\[2ex]
  \varphi'' (h) &= \dfrac{2}{3}f'(h) \C- \dfrac{\C2}{3}f'(-h) - \dfrac{1}{3}(f'(h)-f'(-h)) - \dfrac{h}{3}(f''(h)+f''(-h)) \\
                &= \dfrac{1}{3}f'(h) \C- \dfrac{\C1}{3}f'(-h) - \dfrac{h}{3}(f''(h)+f''(-h)), \\[2ex]
  \varphi'''(h) &= \dfrac{1}{3}f''(h) \C+ \dfrac{\C1}{3}f''(-h) - \dfrac{1}{3}(f''(h)+f''(-h)) - \dfrac{h}{3}(f'''(h)-f'''(-h)) \\
                &= \C{\xcancel{\color{red}{-2f''(-h)}}} - \dfrac{h}{3}(f'''(h)-f'''(-h))
\end{align*}
$$

However, compared with the book,

1. ❎ There is an extra item (marked in red) in my calculation result;
2. ❎ (Of course then) I don't get $0$ by substituting $h=0$ into $\varphi^{(1, 2)}$.

So is there some error in my cognition of some points? Thanks for the help!

---

## A lesson I learned

Originally, from the perspective of *antiderivative* ($F(u)$), it is very natural and logical to apply the chain rule ($(F(u))'=F'(u)u'$) when differentiation.
 However, when faced with the integral symbol, when take the derivative of the definite integral form ($\int_0^{u(h)}{\color{gray}{f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x}}$) of *integral function* $F(u)$, I actually regard $u(h)=-h$ as "a symbolic whole" (that is, the illusion "no need to separate out the minus sign"), and thus "drop out" the chain rule – what a serious **essential misunderstanding**!

**[Conclusion]** For the derivative of integrals, the perspective of antiderivatives is more beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a minus sign error here:

$$\left(\int_{-h}^0 f(x) \; dx\right)^\prime = +f(-h).$$

I'm guessing you forgot the last step of the chain rule which would be to multiply by the derivative of $-h$, which gives you another minus sign.  I think causes your red term to disappear.

EDIT:

Let $f(x) = x$.  Then

$$\left( \int_{-h}^0 x \; dx\right)^\prime = \left(\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_{-h}^0\right)^\prime = \left(\frac{0}{2} - \frac{(-h)^2}{2}\right)^\prime = - \left(\frac{h^2}{2}\right)^\prime = -h. $$

But

$$-f(-h) = -(-h) = h.$$

Not the same.

Comment: The way I am seeing this : the Previous Integral gets f(h) with limits from 0 to h ; If the Previous Integral limits were from 0 to -h , we will get f(-h) ; Now if we reverse the limits from -h to 0 , we will get -f(-h) ; That looks correct !!

Comment: It doesn't look correct, because it's not correct.  When you take the derivative you have to use the chain rule and the derivative of $-h$ is $-1$.  You have to multiply the final result by that $-1.$

Comment: Oh, I think I got where I went wrong (I hope!) : the Previous Integral gets f(h) with limits from 0 to h ; If the Previous Integral limits were from 0 to -h , we will get f(-h)(derivative of -h) = -f(-h) ; Now if we reverse the limits from -h to 0 , we will get -(-f(-h))=f(-h) ; That matches your calculation now !!

Answer (score 0):

I have not gone over all the calculations, but I have a concern here:

---

[image: Q Part]

---

I think here the first term is fine , **the middle term is missing $4f(0)$ withing the brackets** , while the last term is fine because Derivative of Constant is 0.

Comment: Well, I made a slight correction accordingly, but it did not affect the subsequent steps at all, not to mention the results, alas